# Can 勝手に決める by itself carry a negative connotation?

Tags: meaning

As in, to add a selfish and careless tinge to 決める? Here, for instance:

> 「ふうん。勝手に決めて、わたしに負けるのもイヤ？」

Implying that such action (without taking any other context into consideration) would lead the other party to lose to the speaker?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain the situation? If the addressee makes a selfish choice and loses to the speaker, would that be a negative thing for the speaker? I just don't understand where this situation would apply.

Comment: This is a situation where the other person (B) is making plans, which, if they fail, will make the speaker (A) win the game. Both would like to win. 

So the question is, can (A) say that if (B) acts in a way
described by 勝手に決める he (is implied) to lose ("losing to me would suck, right")?

More generally, can 勝手に決める carry a negative meaning without taking any other context into consideration? Can 勝手に carry a rash/hasty/thoughtless tinge besides the regular selfish/wilful one?

Comment: If B's plans make B lose and A win, how is that a selfish action?

Comment: Sorry for expressing myself poorly, let me make the previous comment more precise: 

This is a situation where the other person (B) is making plans for himself, which, if they fail despite (B)'s best intentions for them to succeed and (B)'s interest in them succeeding, will make the speaker (A) win the game. In other words, you can treat it as a tit-for-tat game between (A) and (B).

Comment: So your real question is `Can 勝手に carry a rash/hasty/thoughtless tinge besides the regular selfish/wilful one?`? (Both of which carry a negative connotation in my opinion.) And your question is not about the meaning that can be found readily in dictionaries, `自分だけに都合のよいように行うこと。わがまま。きまま。「勝手な振舞い」「勝手に決める」`?

Comment: Or more specifically: (A) and (B) are playing a game of [prisoner's dilemma](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoner%27s_dilemma). (B) chooses to cooperate, with the best intentions. However, (A) then chooses to defect. Before both players make their choice, (A) says 「勝手に決めて私に負けるのもいや？」 - can that be taken in the sense of `B, do you really want to make a rash/thoughtless decision that could make you lose?`

Comment: A prisoner's dilemma is an interesting (and very illustrative) way to put it, though the specific situation used for this example doesn't involve a cooperative (2-2) possibility. For either of them the outcome is binary (win or lose) and the speaker (I assume) is simply teasing the other party.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the situation yes, it can carry a negative connotation.
It is especially easy to see this situation in school and love-related dramas where people are trying to make plans and there is a quarrel or disagreement over something and one of the parties gives up trying to give input.

> Aさん：　じゃあ、どうする？
>   Bさん：　そうだね．．．
>   Aさん：　どこのレストラン行く？イタリアン？フレンチ？
>   Bさん：　ちょっと洋食は今食べる気じゃないなぁ～
>   Aさん：　じゃあ、中華料理は？
>   Bさん：　それも別に食べる気分じゃないな～
>   Aさん：　もういいよ、**勝手に決めて** <--- Is now angry/fed up